# How can I aggregate a data set and calculate entropy of a continuous variable across groups in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, tidyr, entropy

I would like to calculate the entropy of a continuous variable of each group in R.

Here is an example of the data:

`id group  X
1  1     1 28
2  2     1 45
3  3     2 21
4  4     2 46
5  5     3 82
6  6     3 98`

There are actually 273 groups and more variables other than X.

I would like to be able to calculate the entropy of X for each "group".

I have tried using the group_by and summarise commands in tidyr but I don't believe there is an appropriate command for entropy.

Hopefully there is a simple solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `entropy  = B*sum(p*log(p))` so you could write your own function for entropy

Answer (score 2):

There is an `entropy` package in R.

```
#install.packages('entropy')
library(entropy)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(entropy = entropy(X))
```

Gives us:

```
     id group     X entropy
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1    28   0.666
2     2     1    45   0.666
3     3     2    21   0.622
4     4     2    46   0.622
5     5     3    82   0.689
6     6     3    98   0.689
```

Or for aggregate results:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(entropy = entropy(X))
```

Gives us:

```
  group entropy
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1   0.666
2     2   0.622
3     3   0.689
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 
3, 3), X = c(28, 45, 21, 46, 82, 98)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark, to let others know that it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

in base R, you could do could just write the entropy function outside instead of redefining it each time. ie

```
  entropy_base <- function(x) -sum((x<-prop.table(x))*log(x))
```

if you want to summarize:

```
aggregate(X~group,df, entropy_base)
  group         X
1     1 0.6657808
2     2 0.6218199
3     3 0.6891913
```

if you want to mutate:

```
transform(df,entopy=ave(X,group,FUN = entropy_base))
  id group  X    entopy
1  1     1 28 0.6657808
2  2     1 45 0.6657808
3  3     2 21 0.6218199
4  4     2 46 0.6218199
5  5     3 82 0.6891913
6  6     3 98 0.6891913
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the ddply function in the plyr package:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.6/topics/ddply

This function allows you to pass data, columns to group by, and apply a function.

Example:

```
ddply(data, .(Group), summarise, Entropy(x,Y))
```

Where I have Entropy(x,Y) you could include whichever entropy function you would like.